# Getting value of people picker

Tags: people-picker, person

This is first time i use people picker. I have no experince with it. I hope that somebody can help me with getting value of people picker to save it in a new item as a person in my hosted list in SharePoint online.

This is my people picker code

```
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {
    // Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.

    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['Width'] = '151px';

this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);}
```

and this is the code when page starts

```
initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');
```

and that's what I want. I want to write code instead of the question marks to send the user to the SharePoint list and att the person to person field

```
listItem.set_item("lfua", ????????????);
```

Comment: You want to add it through code? Please elaborate requirement.

Comment: thank you for helping i add some code to my question. now you can see what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include following code:

```
// Query the picker for user information.
function getUserInfo() {

// Get the people picker object from the page.
var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

// Get information about all users.
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();



// Get the first user's ID by using the login name.
getUserId(users[0].Key);
}

// Get the user ID.
function getUserId(loginName) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess), 
         Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
    );
}

function ensureUserSuccess() {
    var <YOURVAR> = this.user.get_id());
    listItem.set_item("lfua", <YOURVAR>);
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```